# PHP DOMXPath Predicate not working for amazon scraping

Tags: php, xpath, predicate, domxpath

I'm trying to use DOMXPath and DOMDocument to scrape ASIN codes from amazon.com using PHP.

I'm trying to get a href attribute from an `<a>` tag inside a `<h3 class="newaps">`.

```
<h3 class="newaps">
    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EJDIG8M" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    <span class="lrg bold">ADX 12-Replacement Charcoal Water Filters for Cuisinart Coffee Machine</span>
    </a> 
</h3>
```

My xpath query goes soemething like this at the moment but it's returning a length of zero when i print_r the variable.

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//h3[contains(@class,'newaps')]//a/@href");

print_r($elements);
```

Output:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)
```

I'm very new to this and have scoured stackoverflow and google for help, not quite understanding how to do it properly. I have a predicate working for another anchor tag something along the lines of the below, but the above issue requires more detailed examination and I'm running low on time to get it sorted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Bryce

Comment: Put all related PHP code please.